# Сортировка по полю связанной модели в ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

У меня есть модели `User` и `Violation`

`Violation belongs to user`

User.rb

```rb
has_many :violations, class_name: 'UserViolation'
```

Я хочу сделать сортировку по дефолту на индексной странице.
Сортировка должна быть по типу `User.violations.first.created_at asc`
Я пробовал что то вроде

```rb
config.sort_order = "violations.first.created_at_asc"
```

Но это не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам придется переопределить `find_collection`, дефолтным `sort_order` тут не обойдешься

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  controller do
    def find_collection(options = {})
      super.joins(:violations).group(:id).order('MIN(violations.created_at) asc')
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

Если есть пользователи без `violations`, замените `joins` на `left_outer_joins`

Comment: Мне пришлось немного изменить предложенный вами код, из за того, что пишу на 4х рельсах. Сейчас он выглядит так `joins("LEFT JOIN violations ON users.id = violations.user_id").group('users.id').order('MIN(violations.created_at) asc')` но он почему то сортирует не по violations.first.created_at

Comment: У вас для `violations` есть какой-то `default_order`? Я имею в виду, по какому полю они сортируются, когда вы запрашиваете first? Если не уверены, вызовите в консоли `User.first.violations.first` и посмотрите логи SQL. Я предположила, что сортировка дефолтная, по айдишнику, и никаких хитростей с датой создания нет - в такой случае запись с минимальной датой создания будет первой в коллекции